# Why does merging dataframes writes off some of my data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I tried to merge two dataframes:

```
df1 contains columns a b c, row 1,2,3
df2 contains columns a b c, row 4,5,6
```

when using `pd.merge(df1,df2)`, some of the row data gets erased and disappears from the merged df. Why?

Comment: Show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: Your question needs to be completed with a reproductible example: data and code.

Comment: Take a look at [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/15239951)

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2)` is not what you expect. What do you want to do exactly, and please provide a [mre] with the expected output...

Comment: `merge` is a SQL-style `join`. Not necessarily an all-inclusive merge of all rows; the name is a misnomer if you don't know how SQL-style works (`how=inner|(left|right|full) outer`).  It's all explained in [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/15239951)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:
`pd.concat([df1,df2])`

It works.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[11, 22, 33], [44, 55, 66], [77, 88, 99]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
```

You will get the table with all elements from two dataframes. `ignore_index=True` helps to avoid confused numeration of index.

Also you can use:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```

You should check https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html